# OOP best design practices for nested classes and helper functions

Tags: c#, oop

I'm programming a project in C# and I have two questions in regards to OOP best practices. To keep my questions simple I have simplified the code examples.

I have a class `Map` which holds the information to the 2D tile map. There will be only one instance of the Map class:

```
class Map {
    int height
    int width
    InventoryGrid iGrid
    TileGrid tGrid

    public Map(int height, int width) { ... }
}
```

The `Map` class contains 2 grids that are related to the items and tiles on the map. These are technically nested classes since they do not get initialized anywhere else in the code. For example the `InventoryGrid` class might look like this:

```
class InventoryGrid {
    Dictionary<int, Item> inventory

    public function SetInventory(int index, item) { ... }
    public function GetInventory(int index) { ... }
}
```

Let's assume we have a `Job` class which in case an action is completed needs to update the inventory.

```
class Job {
    public void FinishedJob()
    {
        // I need to update the inventory.
    }
}
```

Let's assume the `Job` class makes an event call or has access to the `Map` instance.

The first question is, what is the best OO way to call the InventoryGrid.SetInventory() function on the inner class:

1. Create a getter function in the `Map` class and call map.iGrid.SetInventory() directly.
2. Create a new function inside the `Map` class, map.SetInventoryAt() for example, which in turn calls the iGrid.SetInventory() function.
3. Other solution?

Now in our example the map takes x and y coordinates. However the "grids" take a single unique deterministic index to store their information. A function to convert the coords to index is required.

```
public int CoordsToIndex(int x, int y) {...}
```

This function will be used by all Grids (InventoryGrid, TileGrid, etc...)

My second question is where should the function reside according to best practise OO design? Who's responsibility is it?

1. Do I make a super class `Grid` containing the function from which all "grids" inherit to avoid duplication? C# specific: use an interface instead of super class?
2. Do I put it in the `Map` class and argue that the "Grids" should not be aware of the coords to index conversion. Would this affect the first question?
3. Do I make a separate (static) class called `GridTools` which holds helper methods?
4. Other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go a) #2 and b) #1 choices.

If `Map` is a Singleton make it static.

a) #2 because a getter alludes inventory is a member, a function gives you more encapsulation and in future ability to tap into inheritance and interfaces should you extend the object model. Getter's suit single value much better than nested classes. *Edit:* I see you're accessing the getter via iGrid in #1, it's not very obvious to caller that's how you would set inventory. IMO it would be equally acceptable solution to use a getter that exposes iGrid if it was named InventoryGrid. If you have sub-nested classes this would be a better way to go.

b) #1 because logically to avoid duplication in a scenario where 2 grid classes need the same method a base/super class is one of the best ways. You might choose each grid to implement an interface if they have implementation specific `CoordsToIndex` functionality, if this is the case you could also use an abstract base method.

> This function will be used by all Grids (InventoryGrid, TileGrid, etc...)

I think though that both grids will share the exact same implementation and one `CoordsToIndex` base class for both InventoryGrid and TileGrid is what you want right now (at this point in your design). I'm assuming that CoordsToIndex relies on data in both grids, otherwise your idea of decoupling and putting CoordsToIndex in the Map class is a good idea.

With Helper classes keep them more for app wide stuff: Config, File, Encryption, Logging/Tracing, extension methods, etc.

Your top 2 choices for both scenarios are good, so you're on the right track. One piece of advice is that interfaces allow you to use unit test mocking so you may want to write a few unit tests to confirm you can test your oop architecture.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, Google "The Law of Demeter". That will give you good OOP guidelines for exactly this sort of thing. And remember, it's a guideline, not a hard rule.

To answer your second question, put the translation code on the Map class because that's the simplest solution and you can easily refactor later. If you find that you need a bunch of related helpers, make a new Helpers class and move the logic there. If you find that other components need to access the Maps then create a base map class and move the logic there. Always choose the most basic solution because it's the easiest one to change when a better solution becomes more clear (Google YAGNI).

That being said, consider using multidimensional arrays or jagged arrays instead of Dictionary. For me they are much easier to comprehend for tile maps and the translation problem goes away. Making problems go away is better than an elegant solution to a problem.